# After applying transform, face snapping no longer working

Tags: snapping

[image]

After I applied the transform, then I duplicate this cylinder the snapping behaviour goes strange(sideways), I guess it's something wrong with the local axis, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Hello :). Yes, if you apply rotation, the local orientation might no longer match the geometry.